# How to automate a canvas application?

Tags: selenium, testing, canvas, automation, automated-tests

1. Is there any automation testing tool for canvas application.
2. Any possible to automate a canvas application using selenium.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is canvas application? Can you please share some URLs?

Comment: Our canvas application is a game, like chess board I need to drag a image  one area to another.

Comment: check ranorex www.rarnorex.com

Comment: is it HTML5 canvas ?